# I am wanting to make a litter box enclosure but I don't have any power tools or knowledge

Tags: woodworking, cabinets, wooden-furniture, laminate, pet-door

I am just wondering how I can put a kitty entrance in the side of the cabinet I am using without a jigsaw or any power tool of any sort. I also want to add shelving above the cabinet for storage but I am unsure about how to go about securing the shelving. Would just glue work or should I use dowels as well?

Comment: Need more information. What's the cabinet made of? What type of shelving? What are the walls made of?  What hand tools do you have?

Comment: The cabinet and shelving are all laminate and I don't have any hand tools. I am diying for the first time and trying to figure out what I need

Comment: The best advice is for you to look up a few youtube videos and see if any present something within what you believe is your skill level.

Comment: Go to your home store and pick out some basic hand tools and maybe a drill. Find an old employee in the tool section for help.. (the young ones only know power tools .. :-) ).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help

Comment: A decent measuring tape should be the first thing to get.

Comment: Don't ever buy new tools for infrequent use, go to Habitat Restore and get each tool for a buck or two. If you wear down the used one, unlikely since tools used to be made to last longer than now, then go out a get a new version of that greatest hit at harbor fright. If you then wear out the cheap new one, then, and only then, should you invest in a high-quality brand-new tool.

Comment: We'd really need to know more about the construction of the cabinet you're trying to modify, and what you want the result to be. I suspect that you could get away with just cutting a cat-sized hole in one of the cabinet sides, at a height convenient for the cat to enter and leave through, but details depend on how it is built, it's size, and so on. Adding shelving might be easier if you affixing the shelves to the wall rather than this cabinet; otherwise you're essentially talking about building a new cabinet with the shelves and affixing it to the top of this one. Do websearch for examples.

Comment: Have you asked your cat how they feel about a closed cabinet? Our 2 cats have 3 boxes… one open air; the other closed doors; the last, we keep one of 2 doors open. The closed box rarely gets used. The half open one, sometimes. The open air one — super popular.

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion of litter bix alternatives/preferences over on https:://pets.stackexchange.com ... I'd suggest taking the closed/open question back there.

Comment: you need better air movement around the box if it's enclosed.

Comment: This question is too broad. It lacks details about the cabinet and asks several questions in one post. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to be more clear and specific.

Comment: I strongly suggest starting with some more basic projects. You don't want to be modifying cabinetry as your first ever DIY project. Watch videos and read books and get your hands dirty for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of tool - if you don't want to spend money on a power tool like a jigsaw or sawzall, you could look at a manual keyhole saw for about $10-15. The proper tool for making quick work of this, however, is a power jigsaw.

Assuming you're just trying to cut a hole for a cat door in the side of a cabinet, make an outline of the hole with some sort of pen or pencil. You would ideally drill a hole somewhere on the line to get your keyhole started, but if all you have in life is a keyhole saw, you could just start sawing on the surface of the line you made until at long last your saw cuts through the cabinet wall, and now you can use the keyhole saw properly and continue to cut down along the line until you've completed the hole for the cat door.

Shelving is a bit more complex, particularly if you're trying to do it without tools. Much will depend on the shape of the shelving you're attaching, and the profile of the cabinet you're attaching it to.

If the surfaces are flat and line up together, ou could use what are known as [flat mending plates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09GB3X6LZ), to secure the side faces of the shelf uprights to the outside faces of the cabinets.

You could also use metal hanger strapping or [specific safety products](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C7T7L95) to secure the upper section of the shelving to the wall for better security against it tipping over. Make sure the wall side is screwed into the wall studs though, not just the sheetrock/drywall.

If the faces of the shelving uprights and the cabinet do not line up perfectly, you could take a similar approach of right-angle metal brackets to secure the shelving uprights to the surface of the cabinet structure. Make sure the screws you use are of sufficient depth to have a good hold on the wood. If you have the room on the surface of the cabinet, you could consider drilling a hole through the shelf upright and passing a bolt through metal brackets on each side - a flat bracket on the outside and a right-angle bracket on the inside, or two right-angle brackets on either side.

This is a very practical approach to connecting two things together and it won't look very stylish, but it will work. This is not "woodworking" but home depot hacking. But it's very doable and you can do it! The biggest barrier seems to be getting some tools. A cordless drill and driver kit is probably a very good first investment.